# Ajax not working with this .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, jquery, url-rewriting, permalinks

Im developing a CMS with PHP and MVC. I have the follow htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So i have a dispatcher to go to diferents views depends of the permalink on the url.

My problem is that im trying to use ajax for a Login and few things more and cant make it works.

Is there any expception in .htaccess to make this work or i only can put more exceptions on dispatcher to load the .php in ajax?

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
$.post
(
    "../ajax/login.php",
    {
    u:Base64.encode(user),
    p:Base64.encode(password),
},
    function(data)
    {

    },
    "json"
);
```

I tried with:

"../ajax/login.php"

PATH+VIEW+THEME+"/ajax/login.php"

My folder structure is:

```
view
    themes
        standar
            ajax
                login.php
            js
                ajaxInteractions.js
            index.phtml
```

Comment: I think we are going to have to see your javascript.

Comment: Show your ajax call, but most likely, you need to add a `/` or check your ajax call path more specifically.

Comment: agree with @DainisAbols ...also it's good idea to enter the ajax URL directly into new browser window. You can then check what is going on. Be careful with relative URLs - browser composes them from the URL of the parent page (which is virtual and can contain folders which will be put in front of your JS). This can destroy the functionality

Comment: I hope you aren't Base64 encoding those because you think it is secure...passwords should only be sent through encrypted channels (https).

Comment: Is an internal CMS for work, i only use Base64 to comunicate via post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you need to check your path or just use your absolute path like this:

```
$.post
(
    "/view/themes/standar/ajax/login.php",
    {
    u:Base64.encode(user),
    p:Base64.encode(password),
},
    function(data)
    {

    },
    "json"
);
```

And one more thing; it is not always best practice to spread out the code like this ( it's good for PHP and plain JS calls ). For these types of calls, try to keep it more concentrated:

```
$.post( "/view/themes/standar/ajax/login.php", {
    u:Base64.encode(user),
    p:Base64.encode(password),
}, function(data) {
    /** do your stuff **/
}, "json" );
```

Comment: The problem is the htaccess, with that .htaccess all url or path you point with the url go to the index.php on the root on the domain.

Comment: Not, if you point to certain file directly. It will redirect all to `index.php` if no other valid url is found.

Comment: Thanks, its works. i was testing your code and me folfer is called standar, whithout t, but now works.